# Maximum bore & space between bore on load bearing top plate?

Tags: walls, conduit, load-bearing, hole

I'm installing a structured media cabinet during an under stair closet renovation. Closet is on first floor, wall is load bearing, and also has fire blocking since it's connected to the stairs in a concealed space. 2x4 double top plates. I am trying to install rigid PVC conduit from this closet, up through the second floor wall, into the attic. It will act as the central run room for all my cat6a for upstairs, downstairs, and cameras.

If I'm reading the residential code correctly, I don't need reinforcement so long as my bore doesn't exceed 50% of the plate. I was planning on using 1.5 or 2 inch SCH40 PVC but even the 1.5 exceeds 50% since the outer diameter is 1.900".

Few questions:

1. Am I correct that my max bore size is 1.75"?
2. How many bores can I make at this size in a single 16 inch stud bay?
3. How far apart should the bores be from each other?
4. Is there any device that would allow for easy strapping reinforcement to an existing finished wall if I did want to go bigger?

Comment: You can take the entire thing out if there's nothing resting on it. Is there? Is there a rim joist that acts as a flush beam anyway? Please provide more detail and photos.